# Can't start docker after reboot Ubuntu 16.05

Tags: docker, reboot

I'm trying run docker in Ubuntu 16.04 after system reboot .  I created service for it "/etc/systemd/system/openvpnBOX.service":

```
[Unit]
Description=Openvpn Docker
[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/etc/init/openvpn.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=openvpnBOX.service
```

openvpn.conf:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec docker run --volumes-from ovpn-data --rm -p 1194:1194/udp --cap- add=NET_ADMIN kylemanna/openvpn
```

When i'm running this service "sudo service openvpnBOX start i see that service is run, but when i'm rebooting my system, after reboot  i see that service can't start:

```
"sudo service openvpnBOX status"
● openvpnBOX.service - Openvpn Docker
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/openvpnBOX.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-10-01 21:35:48 SST; 2min 51s ago
Process: 1771 ExecStart=/etc/init/openvpn.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 1771 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 01 21:35:48  systemd[1]: openvpnBOX.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 01 21:35:48  systemd[1]: openvpnBOX.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 01 21:35:48  systemd[1]: openvpnBOX.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 01 21:35:48  systemd[1]: Started Openvpn Docker.
Oct 01 21:35:48  openvpn.conf[1771]: Error response from daemon: 404 page not found
Oct 01 21:35:48  systemd[1]: openvpnBOX.service: Main process exited,   code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 01 21:35:48  systemd[1]: openvpnBOX.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 01 21:35:48  systemd[1]: openvpnBOX.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 01 21:35:48  systemd[1]: openvpnBOX.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 01 21:35:48  systemd[1]: Failed to start Openvpn Docker.
```

I can use `"sudo docker run --restart=always --volumes-from ovpn-data -p 1194:1194/udp --cap-add=NET_ADMIN kylemanna/openvpn"` but it doesn't solve my problem, because i woud like understand why my service doesn't work after reboot.

Any idea?

Comment: Use `journalctl` to debug.

Comment: "journalctl -u openvpnBOX.service" show me same errors

Comment: You need to use `After=docker.service` in your service config so that it is only launched when docker service has started. Else you might be trying to load the container even before docker has started. Also if you run it using `--restart=always` then you don't need to create a service for the same. The container will automatically be started on system reboot. Only docker should be enable on boot. `systemctl enabled docker`

Comment: Now i see other error))), i think that better to use "sudo docker run --restart=always --volumes-from ovpn-data -p 1194:1194/udp --cap-add=NET_ADMIN kylemanna/openvpn"